# (NS)StreamDelegate - no error when writing to closed

Tags: swift, foundation, nsoutputstream

When writing to file using `OutputStream`, after that stream has been closed, there is no error, it silently fails to write.

Starting:

```
self.outputStream = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: filePath, append: true)

self.outputStream.delegate = self
self.outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
self.open()
```

Delegate is working:
`func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {`
`//Will report that stream was opened.`

... Writing some text - successful ...

```
self.outputStream.close()
self.outputStream.write(newData, maxLength: newData.count)
```

And.. nothing. No text is written, yet no error is reported.
Does writing to a closed stream not triggering an error? That is, should we check the stream status before writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check the return value from `write()`, which is the number of bytes written to the stream, or `-1` on error:

```
self.outputStream.close()
let bytesWritten = self.outputStream.write(newData, maxLength: newData.count)
if bytesWritten < 0 {
    print("failed:", outputStream.streamError?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
}
```

Writing to the output stream after it has been closed *is* an error, and will be detected by that check.

The stream's `streamError` can provide additional information
in the case of an error, however it is `nil` in this particular situation.

Comment: Thanks. Just got there: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/outputstream/1410720-write after noticing that `write` has a return value.